# "invalid qualifier" error with array.Contains

Tags: excel, vba

my father wanted a macro in Excel, but for that kind of problem he needs Visual Basic. I decided to help him, but I never wrote a Visual Basic code so I was kind of putting the code together from internet forums and mnsd, but then I ran into this problem and I don't know how to solve it.

```
    Dim strArray() As String
    Dim TotalRows As Long
    Dim i As Long

    TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim strArray(1 To TotalRows)

    For i = 2 To TotalRows
        If Not strArray.Contains(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            strArray(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
```

This is only a part of the code, but here is the bug. 
It show an error that says

> "Invalid qualifier"

and highlights `strArray` in `strArray.Contains(Cells...`. I can't solve it so I'm asking here. I think that there is a really easy solution, but I wasn't able to find it online.

Thanks in advice
Tomas

Comment: try removing the `.Value` from `strArray.Contains(Cells(i, 1).Value)`

Comment: Still the same. Could it be syntax or somtehing? I really don't know.

Comment: I think your strArray is not initialized properly, but it has been a long time since I touched vb. Still scratching my head

Comment: `ReDim strArray(1 To TotalRows)` might need to be just `ReDim strArray(TotalRows)`

Comment: Me too. Now I love python or javascript (i code in those) even more, because they make sense and they're so easy compared to vb.

Comment: @TomášHobza [Javascript makes sense? Well that's new...](https://medium.com/javascript-non-grata/the-top-10-things-wrong-with-javascript-58f440d6b3d8)

Comment: @hellyale arrays aren't objects, they don't have members. Hence, `someArray.Whatever` is an *invalid qualifier*, because `.Whatever` can't legally be qualified with an array.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Ahh... I thought the qualifier was the thing before the `.` that's why I was thinking the problem was the array. Thanks

Comment: well the qualifier *is* the thing before the dot... that's exactly what I said ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug well sepends what you do. Things like Node.js is like way out of my level, but have you heard about p5.js? It's really really simple.

Comment: @TomášHobza let's not pollute the comment thread with an off-topic discussion about JS, but the mere fact that a new JS framework appears every other week should be a sign of something!

Comment: @Mat'sMug So how can I find if that value is in that array?

Comment: Like answers are saying: by iterating the array. Or... hmm, you're in Excel, correct? I have a more elegant solution, hold on..

Comment: For the record, your array is never populated, so even if `.Contains` worked, it would always return `False`. There also appears to be an *off-by-one* error with your loop.

Comment: @Mat'sMug `strArray(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value` would have been populating the array (if the `Contains` had worked), but would have been leaving "gaps" (i.e. if cell A10 was the same value as cell A6 then `strArray(10)` would be `""`, and then `strArray(11)` would be the value from cell A11 assuming it was not a duplicate of something)

Comment: @YowE3K right - that's what I get for skim-reading :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Almost certainly wasn't the intended action of the code (the OP probably needs a second counter - one for iterating the rows, and one to keep track of what index to populate in the array), but that's another question.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I hope you only deleted your answer while reworking it to cater for those gaps - the `Application.Match` solution is a good way of creating a "contains" function.

Comment: @YowE3K yeah, but then realized it's not at all what OP meant to be doing!

Comment: @Mat'sMug I suspect that copying the data to a temporary location, performing a "RemoveDuplicates", and then loading the result into `strArray` might actually be the simplest way :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable strArray is a plain array of type string not a List or other object so it doesn't have a "Contains" method you will have to do something like:

```
Dim strArray() As String
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim i As Long

TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim strArray(1 To TotalRows)

For i = 2 To TotalRows
    Dim x As Long
    Dim contains As Boolean
    contains = False
    For x = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
        If strArray(x) = Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            contains = True
        End If
    Next
    If Not contains Then
        strArray(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If
Next
```

Note that Lbound and Ubound will get the upper and lower bound of the array which can change because you Redim the array.  You could also just use 1 to TotalRows since you "know" the size of the array but since I don't know how complex your actual code is I include Lbaound and Ubound in case you need them in your actual code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had on my mind that I would go through it with a for loop, but I didn't know how. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no `.Contains` method in VBA.

You can achieve the same thing using a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dictionary-object) object which has the `.Exist` function to check if a Key exists or not.

```
Dim objDict As Object
Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim i As Long

TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To TotalRows
    If Not objDict.Exists(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        objDict.Add Cells(i, 1).Value, vbNullString
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves this part, but I don't really know if it helps, because i need to have them in some kind of order. I'm not sure, but dictonaries don't have indexes right?

Comment: Correct, dictionaries have keys (string).

Comment: You can still use a numeric value as key but you will have to convert it to string `CStr(Number)`.

Comment: Dictionaries are allowed to have numeric keys.  The key can actually be just about anything.  (I had one question which was caused because they were doing something like `If Not objDict.Exists(Cells(i, 1)) Then objDict.Add Cells(i, 1), vbNullString` and they were wondering why **every** cell's value was added even though there were duplicate values.  The problem was that the key was the `Range` objects and `Cells(5, 1)`, for instance, was a different object to `Cells(6, 1)`, even if the two cells had the same `Value` property, i.e. the `.Value` needed to be explicitly used for the key.)